# cmd console will not exit until VSCode exits

Tags: cmd.exe, visual-studio-code

I start Visual Studio code On Windows 10 from a cmd.exe console.

VS Code Version: 1.39.2

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362

```
19:25:46.32  C:\src\t
C:>code xliop.ps1

19:26:05.70  C:\src\t
C:>
```

VS Code starts in another window and the prompt returns to my cmd console.

In the cmd console, using the EXIT command appears to hang until I exit VS Code. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, `cmd` windows normally are "bound" to the processes they start. This is the default behavior since command line programs typically don't have GUIs (meaning that if the command window closes, input/output access is potentially lost).

That said, simply starting VS Code via `code example.file` on my system doesn't seem to result in the behavior you're describing. It seems like there may be other issues at play.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still looking for an answer.